# How do I point a TypeScript property to a class object in a definition file?

Tags: class, static, typescript

For example, say I have class `Foo` with static method `bar`. Then, I have a class `Baz` with a static property of `Qux` that I want to point to the class object `Foo`, like so:

```
// foo.d.ts

declare class Foo {
    static bar(name: string): void;
}

declare class Baz {
    static Qux = Foo;
}
```

In my implementation, I want to use it like so:

```
// bar.ts
/// <reference path="foo.d.ts" />

Baz.Qux.bar('hello');
```

See, I want `Qux` to point to the class object itself so I can gain access to its static methods without instantiating an instance of it. Doing it like this, however, gives me an error saying "Initializers are not allowed in ambient contexts" because I'm in a definition file.

Is there a syntax for doing this in a TypeScript definition file? I wasn't able to find it in the specification [(pdf)](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=267238).

Comment: When you use the ``declare`` syntax, you define *types*.  Nothing is compiled into the resulting JavaScript, therefore it is impossible to use ``declare`` to physically put a property into Baz.  ``declare`` states that you already have a ``Baz`` object constructed properly *somewhere else* in another JavaScript file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you actually want `Qux` to be `Foo` itself and not an instance of `Foo`, you need to use:

```
declare class Foo {
   static bar(name: string): void;
}

declare class Baz {
    static Qux: typeof Foo;
}

Baz.Qux.bar('hello');
```

Explanation:

```
static Qux: Foo;
```

`Qux` will be a `new Foo()` and static methods will not be accessible.

As opposed to:

```
static Qux: typeof Foo;
```

`Qux` is `Foo` itself, not a new instance - static methods are accessible - but not instance methods.